# How do I go from an array of pixel values to an image file in Java?

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

I have some code that generates an image (a 2-d array of 8-bit grayscale values, but could be anything).

I want to export this image as a .png file.

Which path should I follow? 
I'm really confused by javax.imageio and java.awt.Image.

Comment: show your code ...

Comment: You could create a [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and use the `setRGB(x, y, rgb)` method to set the color of a specified pixel.

Comment: @DonaldWu just something like `int[][] generateImg(int resX, int resY)`

Comment: @aleb200 that's nice, thanks. I thought I always had to go through Raster. But isn't it a bit wasteful for grayscale or binary images?

Comment: Well, I think if you create the BufferedImage passing as imageType the `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` it will perform better, anyways I never tried it so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need [`java.awt.image.BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) as the image object, so you can use `setRGB` to set RGB value in a given (x,y) coordinate.
But to save you image as file you might want to use [`javax.imageio.ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).

Here is a small example to emphasize how to use them both:

```
int[][] img = getImage();

int xLenght = img.length;
int yLength = img[0].length;

//java.awt.image.BufferedImage:
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(xLenght, yLength, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);

for(int x = 0; x < xLenght; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < yLength; y++) {
        int rgbPixel = (int)img[x][y]<<16 | (int)img[x][y] << 8 | (int)img[x][y];
                bi.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
    }
}
try {
    // javax.imageio.ImageIO:
    ImageIO.write(bi, "myImage", new File("myImage.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, especially for the bitwise stuff. It worked.